# How to paste the data only in blank cells in ms excel from some other program using autohotkey?

Tags: microsoft-excel, autohotkey

```
Myvar:=5
F1::
xl:=comobjactive("excel.application")
xl.range("i"myvar).select()
myvar++
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}
return
```

In the above script, when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> key it selects `I5` cell automatically and pastes the copied data there.

Here the problem is that if `I5` cell is not blank it pastes the data on that and the cell is over written.  I want that if `I5` cell is not blank then it should move to the next cell i.e. `I6` and should paste the data there. And  if `I6` is not blank then it should move to `I7`, namely it should paste the data in the next blank cell only. It should skip the cells in which there are already some values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a conditional statement to check if range is blank.

```
Myvar:=5
F1::
xl:=comobjactive("excel.application")
While (xl.range("i" . myvar).Value <> "") {
  myvar++
} 
xl.range("i" . myvar).select()
myvar++
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}
return
```